# Why is the geodesic between 3D rotations scaled by ${1\over\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: 3d, rotations, geodesic

The geodesic distance between points in SO(3) specified by the rotation matrices $R_1$ and $R_2$ is stated to be $d_g = \Vert\log\mathbf{R_1R_2}^\mathrm{T}\Vert_\mathrm{F}$, for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#Log_map_from_SO.283.29_to_so.283.29).

However, I found empirically that this expression is missing a factor of ${1\over\sqrt{2}}$ in order for distances to be restricted to $[0,\pi]$ (intuitively, the maximum arc length on the unit sphere).

The same Wikipedia entry also notes that $\Vert\log\mathbf{R}\Vert_\mathrm{F} = {1\over\sqrt{2}}\vert{\theta}\vert$, which suggests the missing factor if one of the rotations is the identity matrix. However, no proof or explanation of the $\sqrt{2}$ is suggested.

How can I derive the factor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My confusion was caused by imprecise notations for the 2-norm and Frobenius norm.

The logarithm of a rotation matrix is [skew-symmetric and rank two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO(3)), so there is a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ between the norms as explained in general [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/711234).

The 2-norm gives distances in the expected interval.